# Сколько живут cookie при авторизации?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, аутентификация

Есть приложение на mvc. Есть страничка авторизации. Использую form authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="cookies" timeout="1" loginUrl="~/Authorization/Index" />
    </authentication>
```

Ставлю время жизни куков 1 минуту.
Выполняю вход. Добавляю куки набор:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(client.Login, true);
```

На главной странице приложения проверяю авторизован ли пользователь.
Вот вошёл я. Жду 1 минуту, перезагружаю страницу.
Всё равно авторизован.
Попробовал зарубить сессию. Выключил все экземпляры хрома. Снова запускаю приложение, всё равно авторизован. Через какое же время куки перестают жить? И для чего тога в конфиге указывается время их жизни если живут они на самом деле дольше?

Comment: А вы в режиме дебага запускаете? Я к тому, что во время дебага жизнь объектов может искусственно продливаться=> попробуйте в релизной сборке.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы правы. Спасибо. Можете оформить как ответ, я его приму.